# `iter_cols` gives a worksheet object has no attribute error?

Tags: python, openpyxl

After failing a bunch of times to get `iter_cols` to work with my code.

I tried using the example direct from documentation.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = load_workbook("Trying web.xlsx")
ws = wb.active
ws.iter_cols()

for col in ws.iter_cols(min_row=1, max_col=3, max_row=2):
    for cell in col:
        print(cell)
```

>

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "", line 1, in 
>      ws.iter_cols()
>   AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'iter_cols'

Comment: Check the version of openpyxl. try upgrading to latest version

Comment: Thanks a ton. I just updated and it works exactly as its supposed to. I was on 2.3 and now on 2.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check the version of openpyxl you are using.

```
import openpyxl
print(openpyxl.__version__)
```

If that is an old version, you can get the newest version by upgrading

Answer (score 2):

You can upgrade Openpyxl with pip :

```
pip install openpyxl --upgrade
```